# Python telnetlib ending session

Tags: python, telnetlib

If I am using Python telnetlib, is there a way to close the telnet session if that device does not support nothing to terminate telnet session, so no ctrl+something or quit or anything like that.

I need this so that I could use read.all

Comment: I don't have a telnet server handy to check, but try calling `.close()` before the read.

Comment: ...or maybe not. Looking at the source, that isn't going to work. After `import socket` and assuming your session is called `session`, try `session.get_socket().shutdown(socket.SHUT_WR)`. That should convince the other side to terminate its side of the connection.

Comment: Tried it out, but getting this:

Comment: tn.get_socket().shutdown(socket.SHUT_WR)
NameError: name 'socket' is not defined

"tn" is the neme of the session, but what is "socket"?

Comment: It's the name of the socket module. Import it as shown before the call.

Comment: Ahhhhhh me idiot, it is working thanks I sadly can not give you a check mark for successful solution because it is a comment, can you formulate it as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Network sockets let you shutdown write and/or read channels to let the other side know that you have finished that part of the conversation. For a telnet server, shutting down the write channel is an exit. It should finish sending whatever is in the send pipeline and then close the connection completely. That close is an EOF and `read_all` should return. So, assuming you've already got a connection called `tn`

```
tn.get_socket().shutdown(socket.SHUT_WR)
data = tn.read_all()
tn.close()
```